2002 Mazda Tribute - where do I attach the speed detection circuit wire?
Pioneer dmh w2770nex radio install into 2002 Tribute.  I'm using a metra wiring harness, I have two wires left...speed detection circuit and the parking brake on/off (light green wire).  Where do I connect these?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Not an answer, but too much for a comment.
The instructions that came with your radio warn that self-installation is not supported, and then they specifically call out these two wires as having different connection requirements on different vehicles. They say that Pioneer factory authorized installers have the info required to connect them.
If I faced such a situation, I'd send the radio back and buy from a brand that supports self-installation.
If this is your dream radio and no one here comes up with the info you need and you get nothing further from a Pioneer user forum -- if one exists -- you may have to bite the bullet and see a Pioneer installer to get the info. I wouldn't expect them to give up the info for free, but you may get lucky if you're real nice.
